# How to connect Remote Jupyter notebook with PyCharm Community Edition

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pycharm

Tried many things but the Documentation provided in docs is not upto the mark or might be I am missing something.

Reference : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-jupyter-notebook.html?_ga=2.238101510.700071954.1581064290-901414296.1572418784#

The remote Jupyter instance is running in docker.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because you're using community edition? On the link you posted, it says that this is a professional feature which means it's not part of the free community version.